# ¿Cómo mostrar una imagen en un modal mediante JQuery (SpringBoot)?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, spring-boot

La pregunta creo que es simple, pero como me estoy iniciando no he podido dar con una solución simple y me encuentro con varias alternativas que no me sirven mucho.

Ya he validado que el controlador envía los datos correctamente, el único problema es mostrar la imagen que quedó guardada (nombre del archivo) en la BD.

El Front lo tengo con `Bootstrap`, `Thymeleaf` y `JQuery`

En el `html` de un modal, tengo la parte donde debe de ir la imagen:

```html
<div class="card col-4">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h6 th:text="#{label.imglogo}"></h6>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text fs-6" id="imglogoVer">imglogo</p> <!- mostrar ruta de la imagen >
        <img id="imglogoVer" class="rounded mx-auto d-block"> <!- visualizar la imagen      >
    </div>
</div>
```

El id **imglogoVer** hace referencia a la imagen que se debe mostrar, de momento muestra solo la ruta, pero la imagen no la muestra.

Por el lado de `Jquery` tengo el código que captura los datos, entre ellos la ruta de la imagen:

```
$('#imglogoVer').text('/images/club/'+club.imglogo);
```

Pero ahora me falta que muestre la imagen. Sé que que debo definir el `src` con la ruta del archivo, pero no sé como se hace y tampoco que se debe hacer en el `html` para que lo tome.

Comment: Lea sobre el [.attr](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) que resolverá

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tambien puedes tomar el **id** del elemento `<img>` para setear el atributo `src` obteniendo el texto del elemento `<p>`.

```js
$( "img#mostrarImagen" ).attr( "src", function() {
      return $('p#rutaLogo').text();
 });
```

```html
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class="card col-4">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h6 th:text="#{label.imglogo}"></h6>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text fs-6" id="rutaLogo">https://placehold.co/400</p>
                <img id="mostrarImagen" class="rounded mx-auto d-block">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Adicionalmente podrías usar `html` que toma como parámetro una cadena para establecer el contenido *html* de ese elemento.

```
$('img#mostrarImagen').html('<img id='"mostrarImagen"' class='"rounded mx-auto d-block"' src='" + $('p#rutaLogo').text() + "'/>');
```

Comment: Para establecer correctamente el contenido de `html` se debe usar un formato de comillas simples y dobles para que pueda ejecutarse el código sin errores.

Comment: Si, esta opción me funciono inmediatamente... es como la misma idea pero invocando la función.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes el mismo id en dos elementos y esto no es correcto. cada elemento dentro del DOM debe tener un id único. *Para el ejemplo, reemplacé ambos por fines prácticos*.

Supongamos que en en el párrafo con id **rutaLogo** tienes definida la ruta de la imagen o la traes de manera dinámica... Como sea... Capturas la ruta completa y la seteas en el atributo `src` a la etiqueta `<img>` que tiene el id **mostrarImagen**

```js
//Capturar la ruta
let rutaLogo = $('#rutaLogo').html();
//Setear la ruta al atributo src de la etiqueta img con id mostrarImagen
$('#mostrarImagen').attr('src', rutaLogo);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card col-4">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h6 th:text="#{label.imglogo}"></h6>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text fs-6" id="rutaLogo">https://placehold.co/400</p>
        <img id="mostrarImagen" class="rounded mx-auto d-block">
    </div>
</div>
```

Deja un comentario si te quedan dudas o si le di un enfoque erróneo a tu pregunta.

Comment: Si, me parece muy lógico, habia probado algo similar antes y ahora me doy cuenta porque no me funcionaba de esa manera, estaba asignando mal. Muchas gracias, me sirvio mucho para aprender.